# Property of non-object in Laravel

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu with a drop down.
I'm getting an error that says

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/app/views/layouts/home.blade.php) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/app/views/layouts/home.blade.php)

My home.blade.php

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">work<span class="caret"></span></a>
    @foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown)
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            {{ $dropdown->title }}
        </ul>
    @endforeach
 </li>
```

My PageController

```
$dropdowns = Page::lists('title', 'id');
return View::make('index', compact('dropdowns'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `lists()` method returns array and not object. [Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

You want probably use code:

```
@foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown)
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            {{ $dropdown }}
        </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. So in future if its an array I should just do $dropdown instead of $dropdown->title?

Comment: @Chibi When using lists() method yes